# Android, Fragment load on top of other fragment onBack press

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

In my app, navigation using the nav draw opens the Fragments fine. Until I press the back button, then the fragment starts o load on top of another. (like stacking up).

how can stop this happping.

Here is my nav drawer function :

```
private void setFragmentList(int position) { //TODO set Fragments here

    Fragment mFragment = null;      
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    switch (position) {
    case 1: //Home      
        mFragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;

    case 2: //Login         
        mFragment = new LoginFragment();
        break;

    case 3: //Logout
        DoUserLogout();
        break;

    case 4: //Post New Product
        mFragment = new PostProductFragment();
        break;

    case 5:     
        mFragment = new UserProfileFragment();
        break;



    }//end switch


    if (mFragment != null){
        setTitleFragments(mLastPosition);
        mNavigationAdapter.resetarCheck();      
        mNavigationAdapter.setChecked(position, true);          
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
    }
}//end setFragmentList
```

And here is how a load new Fragment from fragment :

```
Fragment mFragment = null;
mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
mFragment = new EditUserProfileFragment().newInstance("Edit Profile");

if (mFragment != null){
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment)
    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Here is my Navigaton XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_navegation" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layoutDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeDrawer"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/navigation_items"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/userContent"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/drawer_orange_dark"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/userDrawer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp">



                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_user_name_drawer"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImgDrawer"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_user_lastname_drawer"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_user_name_drawer"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_user_name_drawer"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ImgDrawer"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewSeparator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"       
                android:layout_below="@+id/userContent"         
                android:background="@color/drawer_brown" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listDrawer"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeparator"                
                android:background="@color/navigation_items"
                android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove this line `.addToBackStack(null)`;

Comment: Muhammad Babar, if I remove .addToBackStack(null) then when navigation in the app, if press back bt, it wont go back to the preview page(fragment)

Comment: Can you post your fragment's xml file ie layout

Comment: then add preview page fragment to backstack only!

Comment: I haved added the xml, thanks guys

Comment: Not the nvaigation xml.Show your layout xml for the fragments.JUst try to add different background colors to the fragments background.I have a hunch that the background of the fragment's xml is transparent

Comment: goonerdroid is the layout transparent by default ?

Comment: yup as far as u are not setting it.